# glsl fragment shader black screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

i try to create a wall that has two colors: top 0.8, 0.8, 1, and bottom 0.4, 0.4, 0.8 and the rest of it i want to interpolate those two colors.

i have these fragment shader and vertex shader:

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 modelMatrix,viewMatrix, projMatrix;

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color; 
out vec3 Color;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position ;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330

in vec3 Color;

void main()
{

    gl_FragColor = vec4(Color,1.0);

}
```

Some parts of my code in c++ :

```
unsigned int ProgramShader,VertexShader,FragmentShader;
Mode current_mode = GPU;
float verticesBackground[] = { -200.0f, -100.0f, -100.0f,
                         200.0f, -100.0f, -100.0f,
                        200.0f, 100.0f, -100.0f,
                        -200.0f, 100.0f, -100.0f  
                    };
int indexesBackground[] =   {   0 , 1 , 2 , 
                    2 , 3 , 0 
                };
float colorsBackground[] = {  0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 
                    0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f,
                    0.4f, 0.4f, 0.8f,
                    0.4f, 0.4f, 0.8f
                    };

// vao-uri
unsigned int BackgroundVao;
// vbo-uri
unsigned int BackgroundVboPositions, BackgroundVboColors;
// ibo-uri
unsigned int BackgroundIbo;

unsigned int ProjectionMatrixLocation, ViewMatrixLocation, ModelMatrixLocation;

mat4 ModelMatrix;
mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
mat4 ViewMatrix;

void RenderBackground()
{   //glLoadIdentity();
glUseProgram(ProgramShader);
//backgroundShader.Use();
/*glUniformMatrix4fv(ProjectionMatrixLocation,  1, false, ProjectionMatrix.m);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixLocation,  1, false, ViewMatrix.m);
mat4 identity;
identity.setIdentity();
glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixLocation, 1, false, identity.m);

glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixLocation, 1, false, ModelMatrix.m);
glBindVertexArray(BackgroundVao);                                       //revine la starea de desenare a cubului
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0); //deseneaza backgroundul, 4 indecsi
*/
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(0.8f,0.8f,1.0f);
glVertex3f(-200.0f,-100.0f,-100.0f);
glVertex3f(200.0f,-100.0f,-100.0f);
glColor3f(0.4f,0.4f,0.8f);  
glVertex3f(200.0f,100.0f,-100.0f);
glVertex3f(-200.0f,100.0f,-100.0f);
glEnd();
glUseProgram(0);    
}
```

glBegin is only for test and it works, but when i try with glDrawElements i get black screen.

```
void display(void) {
switch(current_mode) {
    case CPU:
        RenderCPU();
    break;

    case GPU:
        RenderBackground();
    break;

    case CUDA:
        RenderCUDA();
    break;
}   
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

My main is:

```
int main ( int argc, char** argv ) 
{
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE | GLUT_DEBUG);
glutInit( &argc, argv );
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
glutInitWindowSize(1280, 720 ); 
glutCreateWindow( "Etapa 2 - Cloth" );

glutDisplayFunc(display);  
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

glewExperimental =true;
glewInit();
glGetError();

glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


InitShaders(std::string("shaders\\background.vs"),std::string("shaders\\background.fs"));
glBuffersInit();
ModelMatrix.setIdentity();
glutMainLoop();
}
```

My shader loader:

```
void InitShaders(std::string VertexShaderFilename, std::string FragmentShaderFilename){
int InfoLogLength=0,Result=0;

//constructie vertex shader
std::cout<<std::endl<<"Constructie vertex shader din "<<VertexShaderFilename<<std::endl;
VertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);                            //creez un obiect de tip vertex shader 
std::string VertexShaderCode = LoadText(VertexShaderFilename);              //citesc fiserul si il tin in string
const char *VertexShaderCodePtr = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
const int VertexShaderCodeSize = VertexShaderCode.size();
glShaderSource(VertexShader,1,&VertexShaderCodePtr,&VertexShaderCodeSize);  //atasez codul sursa din string in obiectul de tip vertex shader
glCompileShader(VertexShader);                                              //compilez obiectul
glGetShaderiv(VertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);                    //obtin rezultatul compilarii
if(Result == GL_FALSE){
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);        //obtin lungimea logului
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderLog(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShader, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderLog[0]); //copiez logul
    std::cout<<"EROARE :\n "<<&VertexShaderLog[0]<<std::endl;                   //output log
}else std::cout<<"Constructie vertex shader terminata cu sucess"<<std::endl<<std::endl;

CHECK_GL_ERRORS

//constructie fragment shader
std::cout<<"Constructie fragment shader din "<<FragmentShaderFilename<<std::endl;
FragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);                        //creez un obiect de tip fragment shader 
std::string FragmentShaderCode = LoadText(FragmentShaderFilename);          //citesc fiserul si il tin in string
const char *FragmentShaderCodePtr = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
const int FragmentShaderCodeSize = FragmentShaderCode.size();
glShaderSource(FragmentShader,1,&FragmentShaderCodePtr,&FragmentShaderCodeSize);//atasez codul sursa din string in obiectul de tip fragment shader
glCompileShader(FragmentShader);                                            //compilez obiectul
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);                  //obtin rezultatul compilarii
if(Result == GL_FALSE){
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);      //obtin lungimea logului
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderLog(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShader, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderLog[0]); //copiez logul
    std::cout<<"EROARE :\n "<<&FragmentShaderLog[0]<<std::endl;             //output log
}else std::cout<<"Constructie fragment shader terminata cu success "<<std::endl<<std::endl;

CHECK_GL_ERRORS

//constructie program combinat
std::cout<<"Constructie program combinat "<<std::endl;
ProgramShader = glCreateProgram();                                          //creez un obiect gol de tip program
glAttachShader(ProgramShader,VertexShader);                                 //atasez obiectul de tip vertex shader
glAttachShader(ProgramShader,FragmentShader);                               //atasez obiectul de tip fragment shader
glLinkProgram(ProgramShader);                                               //link-ez programul
glGetProgramiv(ProgramShader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);                     //obtin rezultatul linkarii
if(Result == GL_FALSE){                                                     
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);      
    std::vector<char> ProgramShaderLog(InfoLogLength);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramShader, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramShaderLog[0]);
    std::cout<<"EROARE :\n "<<&ProgramShaderLog[0]<<std::endl;
}else std::cout<<"Constructie program terminata cu success "<<std::endl;
glDeleteShader(VertexShader);                                               //nu mai sunt necesare daca vom lucra doar cu programul
glDeleteShader(FragmentShader);

CHECK_GL_ERRORS

//obtine locatiile uniform-urilor din programul compilat & linkat
ProjectionMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramShader, "projMatrix");
ViewMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramShader, "viewMatrix");
ModelMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramShader, "modelMatrix");

CHECK_GL_ERRORS
}
```

Comment: Please do not include so much code, it's quite hard to read that.

Comment: Well, your indices look sane, so that shouldn't be the problem. However, you are using the call `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);`. The pointer is zero, which should mean you are trying to access indices that are on the server (GPU). Are your indices previously uploaded correctly to the server? Is the index buffer bound? Is the vertex buffer bound? How is the `color` attribute in the vertex shader being set? These are things that should be clear. (We can do without the code that shows loading of shader source code.) :-)

Comment: i put the code that shows loading of shader because there i set some locations: rojectionMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramShader, "projMatrix"); etc.

Comment: Another strange thing. I put another code in RenderGPU that works well in the original source, but in this source i get black scren and after i comute to cpu and again to gpu i get 3 red dots.